# Powerlevel10K prompt shorten strategy

Tags: terminal, prompt, truncate

I am trying to achieve the same effect as setting
`typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_last`
but instead of showing the last directory I want to see the last two, without any shortening.

I tried to adjust `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH`, but it still keep all the chain of directories.